# Add one handler in terms of another?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have a tag with a complex "oninput" handler, e.g.

```
 <input id="x" type="text" name="x"  
  oninput="lotsofgeneratedcocde...."/>
```

I want to add another handler that simply calls that one. My initial though was that this would work:

```
 <input id="x" type="text" name="x"  
  oninput="lotsofgeneratedcocde...." onfocus="this.oninput"/>
```

But it doesn't. What should I be doing? Thanks.

Edit: I thought that onfocus="this.oninput" would copy the reference to the function, that's why I left off the parentheses for a call.

Comment: Does `this.oninput()` not work?

Comment: @Jared It does: http://jsfiddle.net/pQVfy/

Comment: @Šime Vidas - I know, see my fiddle above and in my answer below.

Comment: When you say 'copy the reference to the function`, what do you mean? To call an event handler, you need a reference to the element, the handler name, and `()` to make it run as a function and not parameter.

Comment: It would be better to pull your common code out and put it in a .js file as a function, then reference that function from both handlers.  Better yet, in your JavaScript code in a file, attach the function as an event handler to the elements. You'll find your code much easier to maintain if you separate your markup from your JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

`this.oninput()` (note parentheticals) should work:

```
<input id="x" type="text" name="x"  
       oninput="console.log('test');" onfocus="this.oninput();"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9kNrW/

Answer (score 2):

This could work?

```
... onfocus="this.oninput()"
```

I assume there's no way to have the generated code be outsourced as proper functions that you could call from both event handlers...

Comment: If it's in the same element, `this.oninput()` would work. http://jsfiddle.net/9kNrW/

Comment: @Jared: Right, I came to the same result. But your answer was quicker. So tpdi, should you have to choose between Jared and me, please accept Jared's answer. I'll update just for the sakes of correctness.

Comment: I don't know that you need to change your answer (since it's not wrong), it's just an example of a more verbose way of doing the same thing.

Comment: @Jared: OK, it wasn't wrong, but this/your way is certainly cleaner. And using document.getElementById is less performant ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**
Use parens: `onfocus="this.oninput();"`

If `oninput` references `this` or the event object, you need to add a little more:

```
onfocus="this.oninput.call(this, event);"
```

**Explanation:**
If you were attaching the event handlers in code, your syntax is correct.  Because you are setting a function reference.  Ie,

```
myInput.onfocus = myInput.oninput;
```

But, when attached in the markup, the code between the quotes actually is itself a function.  Eg,

```
<span id="foo" onclick="alert('hello world');" />
```

Is equivalent to:

```
document.getElementById("foo").onclick = function () {
    alert('hello world');
};
```

So your code as written is the equivalent of:

```
document.getElementById("x").onfocus = function () {
    this.oninput; // returns a function reference.  Does not call the function.
};
```

Comment: I had a suspicion that was the case, but I was not confident that I knew that for sure.